# Cloudfront subdomain redirected to main domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have subdomains setup to CloudFront, already listed the CNAME Alternate Domain Names with the subdomains also set the name.com CNAME into CloudFront domain. But when I'm trying to access the subdomain, the main domain page loaded instead. Btw, I'm using NGINX on my server and it's works correctly if I'm not using CloudFront. Is this CloudFront issue or my NGINX configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting Origin Policy to HTTP Only and whitelisting Host in Behaviour